# method configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder) is already defined in class Error when creating WAR file using maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I get the following error when running `mvn clean install`:

> Compilation failure:
>
> c:\path\to\myfolder\application.java method
>   configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder)
>   is already defined in class my.project.tree.myApplication

What am I doing wrong? At this moment I have no idea what gives the error.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hh.palvelinohjelmointi</groupId>
    <artifactId>urheilutilasto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>urheilutilasto</name>
    <description>Squash Score Counter application</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
            <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
            <start-class>hh.palvelinohjelmointi.urheilutilasto.urheilutilastoApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                 <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.java:

```
SpringBootApplication
public class urheilutilastoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(urheilutilastoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Responsible for launching the boot application. */
        SpringApplication.run(urheilutilastoApplication.class, args);
    }

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(urheilutilastoApplication.class);
     }

     @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(urheilutilastoApplication.class);
     }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner scoreDemo(ScoreRepository scoreRepository) {
        return (args) -> {
            log.info("Save a couple of scores :)");
            //scoreRepository.save(new Score("BO3", "Sampo K", "Seppo A", "Sampo K", "1", "0", "", "", "args"));
            //scoreRepository.save(new Score("BO3", "Seppo A", "Sampo K", "Seppo A", 12, 23, 11));

            log.info("fetch all scores:");
            for (Score score : scoreRepository.findAll()) {
                log.info(score.toString());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Error message as show on my console:

> /C:/projektit/SquashScoreCounter/src/main/java/hh/palvelinohjelmointi/urheilutilasto/urheilutilastoApplication.java:[32,40]
>   method
>   configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder)
>   is already defined in class
>   hh.palvelinohjelmointi.urheilutilasto.urheilutilastoApplication

Comment: Show us *application.java* and *my.project.tree.myApplication*

Comment: Ah to make thing more clear application.java and myApplication seem to be the same file.